# How to I call a preprocess function for a view from a custom module?

Tags: views, theming

Lets say I have a view called `widgets`.

On a given page, `/widgets/manage/` I want to add use a function that calls `drupal_add_js` and `drupal_add_css` to change the behaviour and appearance.

If I wanted to make a change to the widget view in a theme, I'd change this file:

```
views-view--widgets--page.tpl.php
```

But, I want to change this in a module, so I can easily switch a feature on when I enable a module.

I don't need to add any other template files, I just want to call a few functions in PHP.

What is the best way to do this, and what would be the relevant hook to use here?

Comment: Define a hook_theme() as well, or it probably won't work. That always was the case.

Comment: No need to implement `hook_theme()` unless you want to introduce new theme functions...

Answer (score 1):

A [template preprocess hook](https://drupal.org/node/223430) would be the best place. The naming convention for those functions is standard so you should be able to use

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view__widgets__page(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_js('...');
  drupal_add_css('...');
}
```

Comment: I've moved some code out of `hook_init` into the hook like this, and then cleared caches using `drush cc all`. Any idea what might be the cause of this not firing in this case?

Comment: I don't I'm afraid - if the name of the template file in the question works the preprocess should work as far as I know. Maybe try with `MYMODULE_preprocess_view_view()` to start with and see if you can confirm that's firing. In there inspect `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']`, that should give you the names of template files that will be used (and subsequently which preprocess functions you can use)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a Views preprocess hook to work in a custom module, you should first kind of register it using mymodule_preprocess_views_view().

In mymodule.module file, add the following:

```
//Register your hook here
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)
{
    if (isset($vars['view']->name))
    {
      $function = 'mymodule_preprocess_views_view__'.$vars['view']->name;
      if (function_exists($function))
      {
        $function($vars);
      }
    }
}

//Preprocess hook for widgets-page view
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view__widgets__page(&$variables)
{
  $view = $variables['view'];
 //do your stuff here
}
```